# Percentile range output across multiple columns in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to showcase the 60th, 70th, and 90th percentile values for given values in a column

***DATA***

```
type    value

Hello   1
Hello   2
Hello   3
Hello   5
Hello   5
Hello   6
Hello   8
Hello   8
Hello   3
OK      1
OK      1
OK      2
OK      2
```

***DESIRED***

```
type    0.6     0.7    0.9  

Hello   5       5.6    8
OK      1.8     2      2
```

***DOING***

My approach is to utilize the percentile function in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

print np.percentile(df,60)
print np.percentile(df,70)
print np.percentile(df,90)
```

This works, however, the output shows these values individually and does not maintain the other columns in the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> df
     type  value
0   Hello      1
1   Hello      2
2   Hello      3
3   Hello      5
4   Hello      5
5   Hello      6
6   Hello      8
7   Hello      8
8   Hello      3
9      OK      1
10     OK      1
11     OK      2
12     OK      2

>>> df.groupby("type").quantile([0.6, 0.7, 0.9]).unstack(1)
      value
        0.6  0.7  0.9
type
Hello   5.0  5.6  8.0
OK      1.8  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Does 'unstack' allow the columns to be maintained?

Comment: @Lynn No, that just moves the multi-index from the rows to the columns. Remove it to see why.